# What Event To Use For Code Execution On Start and When ShowDialog is Closed

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have form (form1) and in that I have button when user clicks it it will open a another form (form2) using "form2.ShowDialog()".

My Problem is I am looking for a event in form1 which need to execute when the form1 is opened and when the form2 is closed.

I have tried Activated and several other events so far I am not able to find solution. There is also event called "GotFocus" is shown in MSDN but I am not able find it in visual studio so I think probably got depreciated.

Comment: @Grant Winney wow I feel like stupid I never realized please enter your comment as answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ShowDialog()`, then execution in Form1 will pause at that point. When you close Form2, execution continues with the next line.

Just place the code that executes when Form2 closes on the line immediately after `ShowDialog()`.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
// place code here that should execute only after Form2 closes
```

If you decide to use `Show()`, then this won't work, but you can still subscribe to Form2's `FormClosed` event, which fires when Form2 is closed.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.FormClosed += (s, e) => { /* code that executes after Form2 closes */ };
form2.Show();
```